# Pausing and resuming parsing in Ragel

Tags: c++, ragel

I'm using Ragel to parse a string in C++. I need to be able to pause parsing for some indefinite time and then resume parsing where I left off.

Right now I'm trying to do this by putting an `fbreak` at the end of a finishing action. This seems to work fine, relinquishing control back to the parent program. However, I'm not sure how to resume parsing. I thought that just calling the code generated by `%write exec` would be enough, but this doesn't seem to be the case. When it gets back into parsing, the reference to the original string seems to be wrong/lost.

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong in C++ here (it's not my native tongue) or if I'm taking the wrong approach with Ragel.

Here's my start and resume code:

```
const char *p;
const char *pe;

void start()
{
    int len = theString.length();
    char chars[len+1];
    theString.toCharArray(chars, len+1);
    p = chars;
    pe = chars + len;
    resume();
}

void resume() {
    %% write exec;
}
```

The first time I call `start()`, my statemachine eventually `fbreak`s out, and then i call `resume()` to (hopefully) continue parsing.

Any pointers on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was some sort of dangling pointer problem. Moving the initialization of `theString` elsewhere seems to have fixed the problem. So basically, I still suck at C.